# Objects in ArrayList for JFrame

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Is it possible to create multiple instances of an object in a JFrame using ArrayList? I can't get it to work.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circles");

    for (Circle newc : tempcircles) {
        frame.add(new Circle(newc.x, newc.y));
    }
```

Here tempcircles is an input ArrayList which I pass to the class. Might exist better solutions, if so, please share.

Comment: What is `Circle`?  If you have a look at the [JavaDocs for `JFrame#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-) you'll find that it requires a `Component` based object

Comment: Circle is simply an object I want to do [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERQcYaaZ6F0[\link] with. It is an object which extends JPanel and has five properties, a position x,y; a radius; a grow-rate and a boolean for the growth.

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The `DrawOnComponent1 example shows how to paint "ColoredRectangles" from an ArrayList onto a panel. The "addRectangle(...)" method of the panel shows how to add objects to be painted to the panel. Your concept will be similar.

Comment: Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will remove the ambiguity and guess work and result in better answers

Answer (score 0):

When you add a component to a `JFrame`, it is added to that frame's *content pane*, which by default has a [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html).  `BorderLayout` accommodates up to five child components, but if you add a component without specifying a position then it goes to the center position, replacing any component previously assigned there.

If you want to be able to place an unbounded number of components in your frame, then you need a different layout manager for the frame's content pane, such as [`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) or [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html).  For example:

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```